# What regex allows me to specify start and end text that the matching text must be within?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I would like to use Regex to have Sublime Text 3 search for a certain instance of code, but only within two bounding strings.  Specifically, I'm trying to find all queries that do not explicitly join two tables.  So for instance, we may have the following code:

```
    <!--- This is a test comment with from included, a match that we would like to avoid --->

    Test

    <cfquery>
        select  test
        from    table1,table2
    </cfquery>

    Test 2

    <cfquery>
        select  test
        from    table1
            inner join table2
    </cfquery>

    Test 3

    <cfquery>
        select  test
        from    table1,
            table2
    </cfquery>
```

I would like regex to match the text within the first cfquery block, and the text within the third cfquery block, but not the text within the second cfquery block.  The Regex that I have right now is:

```
    (<[cC][fF][qQ][uU][eE][rR][yY]>)[\S\s]*?([fF][rR][oO][mM])[\S\s]*?,[\S\s]*?(<\/[cC][fF][qQ][uU][eE][rR][yY]>)
```

However, this Regex matches the first block, and then the entire remaining file, because although the second block doesn't match, it does not stop trying to match until it reaches the "/cfquery" at the bottom of the file.  This makes sense; it's doing exactly what I'm asking it to do.  But how do I ask regex to stop searching at a certain word?

I've tried using anchors ($ and ^ and \z), but either these are not designed for my needs or I'm not using them correctly.  I thought trying to tell regex that a slash cannot be present in the match may be the solution:

```
    (<[cC][fF][qQ][uU][eE][rR][yY]>)[\S\s]*?([fF][rR][oO][mM])[\S\s]*?,[\S\s]*?([^\/]*?)(<\/[cC][fF][qQ][uU][eE][rR][yY]>)
```

But this is matching the same as before, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Try `(?si)<cfquery>(?:(?!</?cfquery>).)*from(?-s).*,(?s).*?</cfquery>`, see this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iyVuPL/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you.  When I use your demo it works perfectly.  However, when I go to https://regex101.com/ and copy/paste it there myself it doesn't work, saying that the slashes must be escaped.  When I try it in Sublime Text 3 (both with and without escaping the slashes) it returns zero results.  Any idea why?

Comment: In regex101, see my demo, I am using `~` as regex delimiters. In SublimeText, make sure you don't have Whole Word option on.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, I see the delimiter now, thanks.  I do not have 'whole word' on, nor 'case sensitive'.  Unfortunately, every variation I try still returns no results.

Comment: Have a look at [my screen](https://imgur.com/a/jrBfDvk).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for sharing that.  I tried the find command exactly as shown on your screen and it did work.  However, when I do a "Find in Files...", it does not.  We have thousands of templates that need checked, so we need to be able to use the find-in-files option.  Do you know if find-in-files parses regex differently or sets different flags by default?

Comment: That is annoying, there is next to no docs describing that. Please check if by chance they left Oniguruma there, replace `(?s)` with `(?m)` and `(?-s)` with `(?-m)`

Comment: I am just a little afraid the lookaheads are not supported. Ok, ditch all options, use `<[cC][fF][qQ][uU][eE][rR][yY]>(?:(?!</?[cC][fF][qQ][uU][eE][rR][yY]>)[\s\S])*from.*,[\s\S]*?</[cC][fF][qQ][uU][eE][rR][yY]>`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the additional suggestions.  Although that works in simple find mode, I still get no results in find-in-files.  I'm wondering if the FiF feature is a little buggy.

Comment: Use Notepad++. It is consistent in its regex engine use.

Comment: The only inconsistent in its regex is Notepad++. Sublimetext uses PCRE fully.

Comment: So I downloaded Notepad++ and tried both strings suggested in the comments and both in the answer.  I got almost the exact same results as in ST3, except in Wiktor's more recent comment; that one returned 4 results (I'm sure there are hundreds).  I thought this was an implementation thing, but with it not working across two separate programs could that indicate a problem with the Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hallmark of an old school implicit SQL join is one or more commas in the `FROM` clause.  That is, if we see `FROM` followed a table name, then followed by nothing but possible whitespace and a comma, then it is an old school join.  Try searching on the following pattern in case insensitive mode:

```
FROM\s+\S+\s*,
```

### Demo

This is working at least on the sample data you provided.  Note that this pattern does not highlight the entire offending queries.  But perhaps for your purposes, just having a line inside the offending query is useful enough.

**Edit:**

If you also want to only find comma joins enclosed within `<cfquery>` tags, then try the following pattern:

```
<cfquery>((?!<\/cfquery>).)*FROM\s+\S+\s*,.*?<\/cfquery>
```

### Demo

The above regexes are intended to be run in case insensitive, DOT ALL mode, where `.` matches newline.  If your tool does not support dot all, then you may use `[\s\S]` to match across newlines.  In that case, the above regex would become this:

```
<cfquery>((?!<\/cfquery>)[\s\S])*FROM\s+\S+\s*,[\s\S]*?<\/cfquery>
```

Comment: This works to capture all of the variations I can think of; thanks!  And amazingly simple compared to my attempt.  However, it also catches many instances that I don't want it to (such as the comment line I edited into the question).  Is there a way to limit it to looking only within cfQuery tags?

Comment: @Nicholas I updated my answer per your requirement.  Also look at Wiktor's comments/answers, as he may have a better option than what I gave you.

Comment: Thank you.  ST3 doesn't support many flags so I added (?s) to the start of your edited regex.  This works on the demo, but ST3 is returning zero results.  I will play with this and post back if I find a solution.  Otherwise, your original response will work great with some manual filtering.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nicholas I gave you another edit.  Your regex tool may not support DOT ALL mode.  Try the last pattern in my answer to see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  That edit still doesn't work in ST3's find-in-files command, although it does work in simple fine mode.